# Looping code for multiple db3 files in R

Tags: r, loops

I'm trying to import a number of .db3 files, and rbind them together for further analysis. I'm having no troubles importing a single .db3 file, but my rbind won't work, despite it working fine for .csv files. Where have I gone wrong?

```
df <- c()
for (x in list.files(pattern="*.db3")){
  sqlite <- dbDriver("SQLite")
  mydb <- dbConnect(sqlite, x)
  dbListTables(mydb)
  results <- dbSendQuery(mydb, "SELECT * FROM gps_data")
  data = fetch(results, n = -1)
  data$Label <- factor(x)
  data <- rbind(df, data)
}
```

Any help you can offer would be great!

Comment: How does it fail? Does it return an error?

Comment: May be good ideas , 1) close connections after use  2) `sqlite <- dbDriver("SQLite")` use before loop

Answer (score 2):

Let's have a close look at that `rbind` call at the end of your loop:

```
df <- c()
for (x in list.files(pattern="*.db3")){
    sqlite <- dbDriver("SQLite")
    mydb <- dbConnect(sqlite, x)
    dbListTables(mydb)
    results <- dbSendQuery(mydb, "SELECT * FROM gps_data")
    data = fetch(results, n = -1)
    data$Label <- factor(x)
    data <- rbind(df, data)
}
```

You've created the object `df`, then you're binding `data` to the end of it and using that to override the existing `data` (note `df` hasn't changed). Great. Now your loop starts again, creating a new `data` object, and binding it to.... `df`. Doh! It's a simple error, but you're binding things in the wrong order. Try changing that last line to:

```
df <- rbind( df, data )
```

and see how it goes.

What you'll be doing differently is overwriting `df` over and over, making it bigger each time. When you overwrote `data`, you went back and recreated it anew, throwing away what you'd just done.

Comment: Thanks for that! I tried re-arranging data and df to no avail. I think you are right though, because the output only shows data for one file, which is always the last file alphabetically in the working directory (i.e. they are over-writing each other). Is there some other way I have overwritten myself?

Comment: Not that I can see here. Maybe you could include a minimal reproducible example so we can see what the problem is?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by minimal reproducible example, this is the entire code, and I have three .db3 files in the working directory. Would you like me to upload those files?

Comment: Found my problem - i was trying to write the new data over itself, rather than writing "data" to "df"